# STL Sort vs median of medians

Tags: algorithm

std::sort() uses the [Introsort algorithm](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/sort.html) that switches between quick & heap sort depending upon the current partitioning ratio.

Is there a practical disadvantage to implementing Median-of-Medians Quicksort in place of Introsort? After all, it's harder to model a  mixture of sorting algorithms theoretically & compute their worst case complexity - though I assume Introsort's would be O(N log N).

Comment: not sure what your question is here?

Comment: Can the person who downvoted explain why? The question should be clear: Is there a practical disadvantage to implementing Median-of-Medians Quicksort in place of Introsort? And someone has already given an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See Musser's original paper on Introsort. Basically, though Median of Medians and Introsort are the same asymptotically, Introsort does less constant work per item and is generally faster. The paper does mention that Median of Medians would be fine as a fallback sort instead of Heap Sort.

David R. Musser. Introspective Sorting and Selection Algorithms. [[Postscript version]](http://www.cs.rpi.edu/~musser/gp/introsort.ps)

Answer (score -1):

From what I remember, Quicksort performs badly on collections that are sorted or very nearly sorted - O(n^2).  Check out Wikipedia's page on [Introsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort) - with a compelling statistic on Introsort vs. Quicksort.

Comment: The median of medians version of quicksort has a worst case of O(n log n) & is worst case optimal

Comment: My bad - I wasn't aware of that, thanks user356106.  I guess implement the median-of-medians and see how it performs vs. introsort for a definitive answer.